# How to fix "Not Found" problem for displaying images?

Tags: django, imagefield, detailview

I'm preparing a blog component of a site, it is created inside an app of a project. It seems that there is no problem except the images are not displayed.

while running, all things are OK, but just the image "alt" is displayed instead of the image. I have images without problem in other pages of this project.

There is a report on Terminal: 
"Not Found: /article/static/images/growth_EWAl68g.png
[14/Apr/2019 17:44:38] "GET /article/static/images/growth_EWAl68g.png HTTP/1.1" 404 6164"
As you can see, Django uses a false address (static folder is located in root of projects) to access the images.

```
class BlogArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to ="static/images")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = BlogArticle
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView, name= 'home'),
    path('article/', views.ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article_list'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    .
    .
    .]
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('contactus', include('sendemail.urls')),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

```
{% block content %}

    <div <div class="container mt-5 bg-light">
  {% for article in object_list %}
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-9 ">
        <div class="post-entry">
            <h5 > <a href = "{% url 'article_detail' article.pk %}" > {{ article.title }}</a></h5>
            <div>
              <p class="font-weight-bold"> {{article.headline }} </p>
            </div>         
            <div>
                <span class="text-muted">by {{article.author }} | {{  article.date|date:"M d, Y"}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>      
   </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{article.post_image}}" width=100 height=100 class="rounded" alt="{{article.title}}">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

```
.
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
.
. 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
.
.
```

I can't understand this condition, It seems that Django should go to static/images/ but it has an extra word (article) at the beginning of the address.

Comment: If I remove homepage path in url.py and change blog url to "path('', views.ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article_list'),", the problem is solved, but I don't want blog page as site homepage.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was simply solved by adding

urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

to project's urls.py and

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
in settings.py.