# how to add an image in a django project?

Tags: django, django-templates

I created a search bar in a Django project and I want to add an image to it. The code for this search bar is in the templates folder listed by Django. Here is the code:

```
                background-image:url(" images/loup.png ");
```

In the same templates folder, I created an images folder which contained the image to display in the bar. But when I run my Django server, the search bar shows on a page, but the image does not. In order for Django to list the image path on the hard drive, I took inspiration from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679766/how-to-fix-not-found-problem-for-displaying-images) and the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/howto/static-files/) and I added to my `urls.py` file this:

```
urlpatterns +=static(settings.IMAGE_URL, document_root=settings.IMAGE_ROOT)
```

and this to my `settings.py` file:

```
IMAGE_URL = 'templates/images/'
IMAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'images')
```

the `STATIC_URL` variable being already defined in my `settings.py` file. I moved my images folder into the `staticfiles` folder generated by Django. The error still reoccurs. Even when I change the path of my image in my index.html file:

```
background-image:url(" ../staticfiles/images/loup.png ");
```

In my `settings.py` file, I replaced :

```
IMAGE_URL = 'templates/images/'
IMAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'images')
```

by:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In my `urls.py` file, I replaced :

```
urlpatterns +=static(settings.IMAGE_URL, document_root=settings.IMAGE_ROOT)
```

by:

```
urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In my `Index.html` file, I replaced :

```
 background-image:url(" images/loup.png ");
```

by:

```
background-image:url(" {% static 'loup.png' %} ");
```

and I moved my `images` folder to the static folder which I created myself but that didn't fix the problem and I get the error in console line *?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:/static/' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist* however I did create the static folder in my Django project. And when I run my `Django server` on the localhost, I get the following error: **Invalid block tag on line 163: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**

Comment: `I moved my images folder into the staticfiles` why don't you use just static file approach then? It covers your needs.

Comment: Personally I did it thinking that the staticfiles folder that was generated should contain all the static files to be read by Django and that it was the only place where Django could recognize my images folder